# CSS Style not applied in HTML

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, html

I have the following HTML Code which style I want to include in a CSS in a different file

```
<div id="leftPanel" style="background-color:grey;
                margin-left:7px;
                margin-top:7px;
                float:left;">
                <img src="images/fa.png">
            </div>

<div id="right" style="font-size:72%;float:left; margin-left:15px;margin-top:15px">
                Lorem Ipsum Text oder Claim<br>gerne auch mehrzeilig
            </div>
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

Now if I try to insert the style in a separate CSS, like this:

```
    #leftPanel {
   background-color:grey;
   margin-left:7px; 
   margin-top:7px;
   float:left;
}
```

And in the HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
<div id="leftPanel">
                <img src="images/fa.png">
            </div>
```

Then the position is changed, getting this result:

[image]

Comment: You may have better luck using the image as a background-image. Add some padding to put the text to the side of the image.

Comment: Yes! I don't know why is not working, no matter if I put it as a class (.) or as an id (#)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zfdUw/1/  what browse is this in? Looks fine to me, mozilla and Chrome.

Comment: its in Safari.@leigero

Comment: check with the parent container width once. maybe width is exceeding

Answer (score 1):

leftPanel is an id, not a class, in your final html. In the css it should be `#leftPanel` not `.leftPanel`.

Comment: Sorry about the missunderstanding, I was just trying with both at the same time. But now I have left them both as id and as #leftPanel in the CSS and the error still persists. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Is the css file loading at all? Change the background-color to red to test this.

Answer (score 0):

Your first piece of HTML has `class="leftPanel"` where your second piece of code has `id="leftPanel"`.

If you have changed it from a class to an id you need to reference it in your CSS as `#leftPanel`.

Comment: Sorry about the missunderstanding. Check my comment above, the error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS matches based on class `.leftPanel` but your div has `id="leftPanel"` instead of `class="leftPanel"`. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 0):

This looks fine to me. Sounds like an issue with your CSS file not being loaded properly. Check to make sure the CSS file is saved in the right location and contains the right ID styles.

http://jsfiddle.net/zfdUw/1/  (does this work for you in Safari?)
HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>  <!--Check to make sure the file is here-->
<div id="leftPanel">
            <img src="images/fa.png">
        </div>

<div id="right" style="font-size:72%;float:left; margin-left:15px;margin-top:15px">
                Lorem Ipsum Text oder Claim<br>gerne auch mehrzeilig
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
#leftPanel {
    background-color:gray;
    margin-left:7px; 
    margin-top:7px;
    float:left;
}
```